# Modal dialog styles being overridden by site

Tags: css, modal-dialog

I have developed a chrome extension that for a particular use case displays a modal dialog on a site. On most sites the dialog works as expected but on certain sites the CSS of the dialog is being overridden by the parent site.

I have made sure that the element classes in my dialog are very specific as to not clash with the sites classes. I have tried adding !important to some of the styles but that is also not working. I am at a loss, is there a CSS trick that I am unaware of or some way to define the styles so that they are respected?

Here are two examples, first the dialog working as expected on https://bikesonline.com

[Dialog working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB681.png)

And now on another site (https://show.com)

[Dialog not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/111yN.png)

Comment: I should note that I am adding the modal from the content script of my chrome extension. Not sure if this would make a difference.

let myModal = '<div>MyModal Content Here</div>'
document.body.appendChild(myModal);

Comment: @j08691 Not sure what an [MCSE] is in this case? The sites are just examples, I am not sure what is causing the issue so I had to provide something for reference...

Comment: Sorry, that should've read, post a [mcve] in your question please. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible

Comment: Got it, thanks for clarifying. It's hard in this case because the chrome extension cannot be shared at this time. I posted images of the result but cannot post to replicate the issue.